# алгоритм по которому числа сортируются по возростанию

Tags: javascript

```js
function with6(){
    let a = +num21.value;
    let b = +num22.value;
    let c = +num23.value;
    let d = +num24.value;
    let e = +num25.value;
    let f = +num26.value;
    let max;
    let min;
    let mid1;
    let mid2;
    let mid3;
    let mid4;
    let max1;
    let min1;
    let max2;
    let min2;
    let max3;
    let min3;
    if(a>b){
        max1 = a;
        min1 = b;
    }else{
        max1 = b;
        min1 = a;
    }
    if(c>d){
        max2 = c;
        min2 = d;
    }else{
        max2 = d;
        min2 = c;
    }
    if(e>f){
        max3 = e;
        min3 = f;
    }else{
        max3 = f;
        min3 = e;
    }
    if(max1>max2){
        max = max1;
        mid1 = max2;
    }else{
        max = max2;
        mid1 = max1;
    }
    if(min1<min2){
        min = min1;
        mid2 = min2;
    }else{
        min = min2;
        mid2 = min1;
    }
    if(max2>max3){
        max = max2;
        mid3 = max3;
    }else{
        max = max3;
        mid3 = max2;
    }
    if(min2<min3){
        min = min2;
        mid4 = min3;
    }else{
        min = min3;
        mid4 = min2;
    }
    if(mid1<mid2){
        rez.innerHTML = min+','+mid1+','+mid2+','+mid3+','+mid4+','+max
    }else{
        rez.innerHTML = min+','+mid2+','+mid1+','+mid3+','+mid4+','+max
    }
    if(mid3<mid4){
        rez.innerHTML = min+','+mid1+','+mid2+','+mid3+','+mid4+','+max
    }else{
        rez.innerHTML = min+','+mid1+','+mid2+','+mid4+','+mid3+','+max
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="num21">
 <input id="num22">
 <input id="num23">
 <input id="num24">
 <input id="num25">
 <input id="num26">
 <button onclick="with6()">сортировать</button>
 <h1 id="rez" style="margin: auto"></h1>
```

написал вот по такому алгоритму с четыремя числами, всё получилос, теперь задача с  6 числами не выходит,использовать sort нельзя

Comment: 1) изучи циклы 2) изучи массивы 3)изучи сортировку массива, к примеру bubble sort

Comment: спасибо за совет, объязательно изучу, но в этой задаче можно использовать исключительно if else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если чисел будет 46?

Сделайте вот так:

```js
function sortInputs() {
  let array = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs input');
  array = Array.from(array);
  let sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
  let parent = document.querySelector('.inputs');
  while (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
    parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
  }
  sortedArray.forEach(function(elem) {
    parent.appendChild(elem);
  });
}
function selfRandom(min, max)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function addInput() {
  let parent = document.querySelector('.inputs');
  let elem = document.createElement("input");
  elem.type = "text";
  elem.class = "number_input";
  elem.value = selfRandom(1, 10);
  parent.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; 
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.inputs input {
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.buttons button {
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.buttons button.add {
  color: #004085;
  background-color: #cce5ff;
  border-color: #b8daff;
}

.buttons button.sort {
  color: #155724;
  background-color: #d4edda;
  border-color: #c3e6cb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" class="number_input">
    <input type="text" class="number_input">
    <input type="text" class="number_input">
    <input type="text" class="number_input">
    <input type="text" class="number_input">
    <input type="text" class="number_input">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="sortInputs()" class="sort">Сортировать</button>
    <button onclick="addInput()" class="add">Добавить input</button>

  </div>
```

### Объяснение

Вы делаете из набора input элементов сначала NodeList, затем Array, затем сортируете его по возрастанию и затем заменяете отсортированными изначальные inputs.

Для работы не требуются id элементов, функции не ограничены количеством, можно работать динамически с элементами - сплошные плюсы.

Будут вопросы по коду - постараюсь ответить.

Comment: спасибо за ответ но можно только с if else

Comment: @Vahan зачем? (+1 символ)

Comment: смысл не сортировка а алгоритмичное мышление

Comment: Берете вот эту строчку и переписываете её под сортировку через if else:   `let sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);`  В остальном код не меняется.

Comment: Так вроде в вопросе написано было, что `sort` использовать нельзя.

Comment: @Denis640Kb не на момент когда я сел писать решение (вроде).

Comment: @adudnik.ru я могу ошибаться, но вроде не редактировался вопрос. Не вижу правок. Но в целом Ваш вариант с добавлением полей неплох. Лайк.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Может и так. Но вроде автор остался доволен.

Comment: @Denis640Kb насколько я понимаю идея была изначально делать только через if else, т.е. reduce тоже не подходит, но вроде как в итоге пришли к тому, что учиться мыслить алгоритмами нужно иначе. (Ваш ответ я комменднул, мне нравится).

Comment: @adudnik.ru а вот это он уже добавил позже в комментарий ))) Но Вы правы. можно автору накидать длинный вариант с `if` `else` )))

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант проще. Зачем такие сложности:

```js
    function with6() {
        var nums = document.getElementsByClassName('inp'); // Получаем все элементы с классом inp
        let arr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){ // Выполняем действие для каждого элемента. nums.length тут это количество найденных элементов, можно так же через forEach
            let val = nums[i].value; // Получаем значение каждого элемента
            arr.push(val); // Добавляем в массив
        }

        let obj = arr.reduce((o, v, i) => { o[v] = v; return o; }, {});  // Проводим сортировку массива
        arr = Object.keys(obj).map(num => parseInt(num)); // Пересобираем массив.

        document.getElementById('rez').innerText = arr;
        console.log(arr); // выводим новый массив
    }
```

```html
<input id="num21" class="inp">
<input id="num22" class="inp">
<input id="num23" class="inp">
<input id="num24" class="inp">
<input id="num25" class="inp">
<input id="num26" class="inp">
<button onclick="with6()">сортировать</button>
<h1 id="rez" style="margin: auto"></h1>
```